# Getting User input with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to have a scanner take input in a loop. Once the user wants to finish he can exit this loop. I have tried many different ways to do it but there is always some problem. This is the code:

```
private void inputEntries() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Continue?[Y/N]");
    while (sc.hasNext() && (sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))) {//change here
        System.out.println("Enter first name");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter surname");
        String surname = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        Student student = new Student(name, surname, number);
        students.add(student);
        try {
            addToFile(student);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TextReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("Continue?[Y/N]");
    }
}
```

The problem with the code above, which also happens on different methods I tried, is that when the user types *Y*, the `Scanner` will skip the first input for first name,and jump to the surname. If the user types *N* the loop stops correctly. Someone can explain the reason this happens, and how to overcome using `Scanner` class?

p.s: Doing something like `while(sc.nextLine().equals("Y"))`, will cause the loop to terminate before getting input from user after first run of the loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you are using [`Scanner#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) method. And if you look at the documentation of that method, it returns the next token read.

So, when you read user input using `next` method, it does not read the `newline` at the end. Which is then read by the `nextLine()` inside the `while` loop. And thus, your `firstName` contains a `newline` without you knowing.

So, you should use `nextLine()` in your while rather than `next()`.

Similar is the case with [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method. It also does not read the newline. So, you can `read` using `readLine` and convert it to `int` using `Integer.parseInt`. It can throw `NumberFormatException` if input value cannot be converted to `int`. So you need to handle it accordingly.

You can try the below code: -

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Continue?[Y/N]");
while (sc.hasNext() && (sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))) {//change here
    System.out.println("Enter first name");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter surname");
    String surname = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter number");
    int number = 0;
    try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Continue?[Y/N]");
}
```

But, note one thing, if you enter a value that cannot be passed to `Integer.parseInt` you will get an exception, and that input will be skipped. For that case, you need to handle it by using `while` loop.

**Or, if you don't want to do that exception handling**: -

You can add an `empty sc.nextLine()` after `sc.nextInt()`, that will consume the `newline` left over, like this: -

```
    // Left over part of your while loop

    String surname = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter number");
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); // To consume the left over newline;
    System.out.println("Continue?[Y/N]");
```

Comment: Indeed its working. Although Im not completely sure why the nextInt was not working.. I typed a number and hit enter..

Comment: @Giannis. If you see the documentation of [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29), it says that, it reads the `next` integer token, thus leaves the newline that will also be the part of input.

Comment: @Giannis. So, that `newline` will be read next time when you invoke `nextLine` and hence that part of reading will be skipped.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp. Thanks. :)  that part is always a problem with the beginners, when they get user input with Scanner.

Comment: @RohitJain even I was missing it until I used `nextLine()` and read your post :P

Comment: Right got it now should have checked doc.. Im gonna hide in a cave and burn my degree for heat... :P

Comment: @Giannis. Great. Remember, everytime you see strange behaviour with some pre-defined method, you always have `documentation` to look at. They say what actually that method will do.

Comment: sc.next() didnt fix the problem (after nextInt). Used sc. skip("\n") instead.

Comment: @Giannis. Oh! Sorry. sc.next() will not read the `newline`. It just reads next token. You can use `sc.nextLine` instead. I'll improve my post.

Answer (score 4):

- Use `equalsIgnoreCase(..)` to prevent the case of *Y* or *N* being lower case and vice versa.
- Don't use `sc.next()` rather `sc.nextLine()` to achieve what you want, because `next()` only reads up to the next space while `nextLine()` reads up to the next `\n` break.
- Don't use `nextInt()` read all data as `String` and then convert because `nextInt()` is like `next()` thus is does not read up to the next *\n*.

Try it like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Continue?[Y/N]");

while (sc.hasNext() && (sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))) {//change here

    System.out.println("Enter first name");
    String name = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter surname");
    String surname = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter number");

    int number=0;

    try {
    number = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());//read int as string using nextLine() and parse
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Continue?[Y/N]");
}
```

Comment: Continue?[Y/N]
Y
Enter first name
dsa
Enter surname
asd
Enter number
21
Continue?[Y/N]
Y
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds)

Thats what happens.

Comment: I copy pasted the while line and the thing shown on comment happens. Is it working for you??

Comment: @Giannis you have `Enter number 21 Continue?` you did not include that in yourquestions snippet include entire code something else may be at fault

Comment: @Rohit Jain figured I should use nextLine and parseInt.. Its still strange that nextInt cause problem tho..

Comment: @Giannis as said its because `nextInt` reads next token and not up to the next newline

Comment: @Giannis. I have given a work around in my post, for not using exception handling. You can look at that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
String abc = "abc";
String answer = "null";
while (abc.equals("abc")
{
if (answer.equals("n")
{
break;
}
while (answer.equals("y"))
{
//Put your other code here
System.out.print("Continue? [y/n]")
answer = input.nextLine();
if (answer.equals("n")
{
break;
}
}
}
```

That should stop the program when the input is

```
"n"
```

You will also have to import and create the Scanner like this:

```
//This is how you import the Scanner
import java.util.Scanner;
//This is how you create the Scanner
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
/**
*The name
*/
"input"
/**
*is used because of
*/
input.nextLine
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void display() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (j = i; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (j = 1; j < (2 * i); j++) {
            System.out.print(i % 2);
        }
        for (j = 1; j < ((5 * 2) - (i * 2)); j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (j = 1; j < (2 * i); j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (j = i; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        for (j = 1; j < ((5 * 2) - (i * 2)); j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (j = 1; j < (2 * i); j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1       1
   000     123
  11111   12345
 0000000 1234567
111111111123456789
 1234321 1234567
  12321   12345
   121     123
    1       1
output

Comment: I formatted your code, if you add the output to the answer and add some explanation, this could actually be helpful. You can always edit your own answer.