# Enum Error in Code

Tags: java

I wrote this piece of code 
but when I try to compile it says:

```
 error: class, interface, or enum expected
 }
 ^
1 error
```

How can I fix that? I don't understand. Is something wrong with the parentheses? What does enum mean? I have checked the parenthesis and everything seems in order.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Horoscope {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Please enter month of Birth: ");
    Scanner month = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter day of Birth: ");
    Scanner day = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Your horoscope is ");

    if ((month == 3 && day >= 21 && day <= 31) || (month == 4 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
        System.out.print("Aries");
     }
   if ((month == 4 && day >= 20 && day <= 30) || (month == 5 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
        System.out.print("Taurus");
     }
   if ((month == 5 && day >= 21 && day <= 31) || (month == 6 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
        System.out.print("Gemini");
     }
   if ((month == 6 && day >= 21 && day <= 30) || (month == 7 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
       System.out.print("Cancer");
     }
  if ((month == 7 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 8 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
        System.out.print("Leo");
     }
  if ((month == 8 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 9 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
        System.out.print("Virgo");
     }
  if ((month == 9 && day >= 23 && day <= 30) || (month == 10 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
        System.out.print("Libra");
     }
  if ((month == 10 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 11 && day >= 1 && day <= 21)) {
        System.out.print("Scorpio");
     }
  if ((month == 11 && day >= 22 && day <= 30) || (month == 12 && day >= 1 && day <= 21)) {
        System.out.print("Sagittarius");
     }
  if ((month == 12 && day >= 22 && day <= 31) || (month == 1 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
        System.out.print("Capricorn");
     }
  if ((month == 1 && day >= 20 && day <= 31) || (month == 2 && day >= 1 && day <= 18)) {
        System.out.print("Aquarius");
     }
  if ((month == 2 && day >= 19 && day <= 29) || (month == 3 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
        System.out.print("Pisces");
    }
}
}
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "You checked"? There are clearly superfluous braces there.

Comment: @RealSkeptic What do you mean by braces? { or ( ? Can you please help? I am really new to this :)

Comment: You have two extra `}`. But they just mask several other errors.

Comment: remove two `}` from last part of the code, and i believe you need to read from the user the month and the day, by  using `Scanner month = new Scanner(System.in)` you are just tell the compiler to use the in stream  only . you have to say `int mnth = month.nextInt()`

Comment: "Braces" in English mean `{}` (full name: "curly braces"). Brackets mean `[]` (full name: square brackets). And parentheses mean `()`.

Comment: @Marwin yeah, when I try removing those, everything else fails. What is the problem? I don't seem to understand. I used the correct if statements didn't I? it says I can't compare scanner to int. How should I fix that?

Comment: It's not that everything else fails. It's that when you have such a serious error as unbalanced braces, the compiler does not go into the details of the program itself and quits immediately. Once you fix the serious error, it starts complaining about the content of the actual code.

Comment: And as for the actual content errors - look at your code. When you compare `month == 3`, what type is `month`? Does that make sense? Look at the example code you got at school. Did you do the correct thing when you declare `month` and `day` like that?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks :)  Ali Helmy is right. I need to make it next int = month.nextInt()

Comment: @AliHelmy Shukran :)

Comment: Welcome bro :) , please accept an answer to close the question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Scanner month = new Scanner(System.in)` you are just tell the compiler to use the in stream only . you have to say `int mnth = month.nextInt()`
Change this part

```
System.out.println("Please enter month of Birth: ");
Scanner month = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter day of Birth: ");
Scanner day = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Your horoscope is ");
```

with

```
int month=0 , day=0;
Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter month of Birth: ");
month = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter day of Birth: ");
day = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Your horoscope is ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Few things you should study before you start to write the code.

- [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) (JavaDoc for the class Scanner)
- [How to take input using `Scanner` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13000013/4338417)

This is your correct code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Horoscope {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter month of Birth: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int month = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter day of Birth: ");
        int day = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your horoscope is ");

        if ((month == 3 && day >= 21 && day <= 31) || (month == 4 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
            System.out.print("Aries");
        }
        if ((month == 4 && day >= 20 && day <= 30) || (month == 5 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
            System.out.print("Taurus");
        }
        if ((month == 5 && day >= 21 && day <= 31) || (month == 6 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
            System.out.print("Gemini");
        }
        if ((month == 6 && day >= 21 && day <= 30) || (month == 7 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            System.out.print("Cancer");
        }
        if ((month == 7 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 8 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            System.out.print("Leo");
        }
        if ((month == 8 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 9 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            System.out.print("Virgo");
        }
        if ((month == 9 && day >= 23 && day <= 30) || (month == 10 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            System.out.print("Libra");
        }
        if ((month == 10 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 11 && day >= 1 && day <= 21)) {
            System.out.print("Scorpio");
        }
        if ((month == 11 && day >= 22 && day <= 30) || (month == 12 && day >= 1 && day <= 21)) {
            System.out.print("Sagittarius");
        }
        if ((month == 12 && day >= 22 && day <= 31) || (month == 1 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
            System.out.print("Capricorn");
        }
        if ((month == 1 && day >= 20 && day <= 31) || (month == 2 && day >= 1 && day <= 18)) {
            System.out.print("Aquarius");
        }
        if ((month == 2 && day >= 19 && day <= 29) || (month == 3 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
            System.out.print("Pisces");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but you only put one scanner?

Comment: One `Scanner` is enough for the entire program. `Scanner` defines the input stream. And with `.nextInt()`, you take the next integer input. You can take any number of inputs using a single `Scanner`. Refer the links in the answer. That will help you understand better.