# User input using Scanner class

Tags: java

How get string input from user using `scanner`.
e.g:

```
Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);

String name = get.nextString();
```

But calling doesn't work with string but it works with integers or double data types.

Comment: `String name = get.nextString( );` Write types uppercase and don't forget the brackets at the end of a method call.

Comment: try,    String name = get.next() ; 
And for such minor issues please read your tutorial guides well before asking, java docs , tutorialspoint ,  javatpoint , are some good places if you want to learn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting User input with Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999899/getting-user-input-with-scanner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `new Scanner().nextLine()` or just `new Scanner().next()` because there is no `nextString()` method in the `Scanner`;

Answer (score 0):

You should call `next()` method instead of `nextString()`.